# Heroku run command throws timeout await

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-syncdb

Whenever I run

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

or

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

it console "Timeout await process", I have even tried

```
telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
```

it console
Trying 50.19.103.36...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
How do i solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can get around this error by using run:detached as per this post : [Heroku run command throws timeout await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960364/heroku-run-command-throws-timeout-await)

Effectively try :

```
heroku run:detached python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 1):

> Timeout awaiting process
>
> The heroku run command opens a connection to Heroku on port 5000. If
>   your local network or ISP is blocking port 5000, or you are
>   experiencing a connectivity issue, you will see an error similar to:
>
> $ heroku run rails console Running rails console attached to
>   terminal...  Timeout awaiting process
>
> You can test your connection to Heroku by trying to connect directly
>   to port 5000 by using telnet to rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com. A
>   successful session will look like this:
>
> $ telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000 Trying 50.19.103.36...
>   Connected to ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Escape
>   character is '^]'.
>
> If you do not get this output, your computer is being blocked from
>   accessing our services. We recommend contacting your IT department,
>   ISP, or firewall manufacturer to move forward with this issue.

I took that from the heroku documentation which can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos)

So run

```
telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com
```

on your shell. You have omitted the "runtime" in your command.

Comment: Are you behind a special firewall?

Comment: Sorry, but i have no idea about it. How can I check that?

Comment: If you are in a network of a company, you are probably behind a special firewall.